# Python library for Multisignature HD wallets

Tags: python, bip32-hd-wallets, mnemonic-seed

Is there is any python library is available that allow creation of Multisignature HD wallets ?

Answer (score 3):

Stepan Snigirev's `embit` library: https://github.com/diybitcoinhardware/embit/blob/master/src/embit/bip32.py

It powers the Specter DIY hardware wallet, Specter Desktop software wallet, and the SeedSigner and Krux DIY signing devices.

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin SE Keith!

Comment: Thanks @MichaelFolkson! Looking forward to finding the niches where I can provide some value and moreso to learning a ton while I lurk!

Answer (score 0):

Python bitcoinlib maybe? See: https://coineva.com/create-multisig-wallet-bitcoin-python.html

Answer (score 0):

you can create them by combining existing Python libraries for HD wallets (e.g., "pycoin" or "hd-wallet-derive") with Bitcoin libraries (e.g., "python-bitcoinlib" or "pycryptodomex") that handle multisignature functionality.